# Is the "modules" tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just reviewing some suggested edits, and saw two questions that someone has retagged with [modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules).

Is this tag really useful?

Considering how much of Drupal revolves around modules in one form or another, does using this tag really help with differentiating one question from another or aid in search in any way?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I edited the excerpt for the tag wiki to use the following text:

> This tag is for questions about modules hosted on Drupal.org. It should not be used to generally mean "this question is about a module," when the question is about a module's code, or when the question is already using a tag specific for the module, such as "views," "cck," or "pathauto."

Clearly, [modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules), and [themes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes) need to be limited in scope, or most of the questions, if not all, would used one of those. Excluding the tag for questions about module's code is essentially because in most of the cases using [modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) for those questions creates a false dichotomy: If the question, for example, is about using `drupal_add_js()` in a module, the question is not different from using the same function in a theme's code.